# Whitespace when rendering using EJS

Tags: node.js, express, polymer, ejs

I want to pass an Object rendered using EJS them pass into an polymer element. 
Why I got `addressLine1&quot;:&quot;123" abc"`, what wrong with whitespace character and is there any way to pass object into polymer element without expose it on HTML like this.

**EJS**

```
<g-map customer=<%- JSON.stringify(customer) %> vehicles = <%= JSON.stringify(vehicles) %> ></g-map>
```

**After rendering :**

```
<g-map customer="{&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;5658013d7e6908d4b370c3f0&quot;,&quot;coordinates&quot;:[10.764221,106.656368],&quot;phone&quot;:&quot;09090909&quot;,&quot;addressLine1&quot;:&quot;123" abc","email":"customer1@gmail.com"}="">
```

**Routes file :**

```
res.render('vehicles', 
    { 
        title: 'Vehicles Managerment',
        customer : req.session.customer,
        vehicles : body.data
    });
```

**customer object**

```
"customer": {
          "_id": "5658013d7e6908d4b370c3f0",
          "coordinates": [
            12345,
            12345
          ],
          "addressLine1": "123 ABC",
          "email": "customer1@gmail.com",
          "username": "customer1@gmail.com"
        }
```

Comment: White space has nothing to do here,EJS while rendering your content is converting double quotes to &quot; to have correct string in your HTML (to avoid " inside string quoted by ").  Try using single quote ' in your object

Comment: But I get this from mongo

Comment: try replacing double quotes with single, before feeding it for rendering. I know this is hacky way, but to figure out if this is the problem.

Comment: @Mannu, thank you, I've found that I have to put rendered object in single quote mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching, I've figured out that I have to put rendered object in single quote mark, so it will treat whitespace the right way.

```
<g-map customer='<%- JSON.stringify(customer) %>' vehicles = '<%= JSON.stringify(vehicles) %>'
```

Comment: On a somewhat related note, if the `<%- string %>` is being printed somewhere inside an html element and not as a tag, then `<pre></pre>` wrapping is required to preserve whitespaces stringified by JSON